# Does Blade Mail really returns damage from all sources or are there some skills whose damage it wont return?

Tags: dota-2

Does Blade Mail really returns all damage like in its description, or are there any skills whose damage wont be returned?

**This is what i want to know**:

Will it return:

- magical damage from AoE attacks?
- damage from DoT spells?
- damage from channeled ults like the one of Pudge or Bane?

List of all skills whose damage isn't returned by blade mail, if there are any.

Comment: as a side note, returned blademail damage is considered pure damage, which can be blocked by BKB

Comment: @spartacus Erm.. doesn't BKB only give immunity to magic damage? As far as i know pure damage is not considered either physical nor magic and it penetrates both magic resistance/immunity and armor.

Comment: nope, pure damage has the property of ignoring armor/resistance but its actually considered magical.  Its pretty easy to test in a custom game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not reflect HP removal abilities, but thats it.

You can find a list of HP removal skills at:

http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/HP_removal#HP_Removal

Everything else is being returned as indicated (note that BKB makes you immune to the return damage).

Comment: AFAIK in DotA 1 there was a threshold. you need at least 1 or 2 dmg to trigger blademail and it can only return a max of 7 or 9000 in one instance. Not sure if they fixed this in DotA 2.

Comment: Note that abilities such as Pugna's Life Drain are ignored by Blademail, even if it doesn't actually change your max life.